# Port is open but I can't ssh to it

Tags: ssh, firewall

My company PC is behind the firewall, I want to connect to my remote server.  The port is open however I can not connect to it, does anyone know the root cause?

From my company PC connect to my remote server:

```
# telnet my-server 2221
Trying x.x.x.x...
Connected to my-server.
Escape character is '^]'.
^C^C^C
# nc -vzw5 my-server 2221
Connection to my-server 2221 port [tcp/rockwell-csp1] succeeded!
# ssh -vvv my-server -p 2221
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to my-server [x.x.x.x] port 2221.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
^C
```

The process will stuck forever.

However at the same time, I check my remote server status, I can clearly saw the connection has been established:

```
# netstat -at
tcp        0    402 myserver:ssh             x.x.x.x:11307     ESTABLISHED
```

After a while, the connection status will change to FIN_WAIT1, then closed:

```
 # netstat -at
    tcp        0    402 myserver:ssh             x.x.x.x:11307     FIN_WAIT1
```

Tcpdump on server side while client initiate a connection request:

```
# tcpdump -i ppp0 port 2221 -vv
tcpdump: listening on ppp0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
12:09:01.408239 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [S.], cksum 0x21e6 (correct), seq 2805531925, ack 581774329, win 14400, options [mss 1452,sackOK,TS val 9959078 ecr 74287789,nop,wscale 4], length 0
12:09:01.424747 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 41302, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    client_ip.20999 > server_ip.2221: Flags [.], cksum 0x8711 (correct), seq 1, ack 1, win 457, options [nop,nop,TS val 74287802 ecr 9959078], length 0
12:09:01.448272 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 62398, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 454)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5dba (correct), seq 1:403, ack 1, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9959082 ecr 74287802], length 402
12:09:01.674641 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 62399, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 454)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5da3 (correct), seq 1:403, ack 1, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9959105 ecr 74287802], length 402
12:09:01.904523 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 62400, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 454)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5d8c (correct), seq 1:403, ack 1, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9959128 ecr 74287802], length 402
12:09:02.364225 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 62401, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 454)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5d5e (correct), seq 1:403, ack 1, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9959174 ecr 74287802], length 402
12:09:03.283694 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 62402, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 454)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5d02 (correct), seq 1:403, ack 1, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9959266 ecr 74287802], length 402
12:09:05.122593 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 62403, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 454)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5c4a (correct), seq 1:403, ack 1, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9959450 ecr 74287802], length 402
12:09:08.810407 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 62404, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 454)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5ad9 (correct), seq 1:403, ack 1, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9959819 ecr 74287802], length 402
12:09:15.006311 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 17769, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.4708: Flags [F.], cksum 0x0499 (correct), seq 1497941342, ack 2936162453, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9960438 ecr 74001029], length 0
12:09:16.176090 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 62405, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 454)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [P.], cksum 0x57f8 (correct), seq 1:403, ack 1, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9960556 ecr 74287802], length 402
12:09:30.927316 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 62406, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 454)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [P.], cksum 0x5234 (correct), seq 1:403, ack 1, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9962032 ecr 74287802], length 402
12:10:00.429743 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 62407, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 454)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [P.], cksum 0x46ac (correct), seq 1:403, ack 1, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9964984 ecr 74287802], length 402
12:10:59.354673 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 62408, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 454)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [P.], cksum 0x2fa4 (correct), seq 1:403, ack 1, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9970880 ecr 74287802], length 402
12:12:57.364324 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 62409, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 454)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [P.], cksum 0x0184 (correct), seq 1:403, ack 1, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9982688 ecr 74287802], length 402
12:14:01.653934 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 62410, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [F.], cksum 0x0e69 (correct), seq 403, ack 1, win 900, options [nop,nop,TS val 9989120 ecr 74287802], length 0
```

Comment: Is a VPN involved? Run `tcpdump port 22` as root, make a login attempt, and post the output, obscuring the host names.

Comment: @Gilles No VPN, I do what you were required:

Comment: # tcpdump -i ppp0 port 2221 -vv
tcpdump: listening on ppp0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 65535 bytes
12:09:01.408239 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    server_ip.2221 > client_ip.20999: Flags [S.], cksum 0x21e6 (correct), seq 2805531925, ack 581774329, win 14400, options [mss 1452,sackOK,TS val 9959078 ecr 74287789,nop,wscale 4], length 0
12:09:01.424747 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 41302, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)

Comment: Add the full tcpdump output to your question. It's unreadable in comments.

Comment: @Gilles I've added in my question, thanks man.

Comment: Only a single packet from the client. This does look like a firewall problem. Though there's something I don't understand: why is the first packet from the server? Is that from a connection already in progress?

Comment: Your client is connecting to port 2221, but you showed netstat for port 22. And now your tcpdump also shows the server port as 2221. What is actually listening for connections on port 2221? How are connections from the client to port 2221 getting to port 22 on the server?

Comment: @Kenster Well, actually the server is listening on 22, I redirected the 2221 to 22 on the router to make sure the security.

Comment: @Gilles I don't know, maybe because I tried for multiple times. But anyway I agree with you, there has an firewall issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
debug1: Connection established.
[...]
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
^C
```

When a client connects to an SSH server, the first data exchange is that the server and client send their version strings to each other. The OpenSSH client normally logs this immediately after the list of identity files, for example from my system:

```
[...]
debug1: identity file /home/devuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
```

Your client never logged receiving the SSH version string from the server. One of three things is probably happening:

1. A firewall or something similar is blocking or dropping TCP data packets from the server to the client.
2. The client is connecting to an SSH server, but it's malfunctioning.
3. The client is connecting to something other than an ssh server.

You'll need to troubleshoot this on the server. The OpenSSH server logs through syslog. You should start by checking the syslog logs to see what if anything sshd logged about the connection attempt.

Comment: How can I check the firewall? Cause the port is open, the route is ok, how should I verify the firewall configurations?

Comment: I'm not a network engineer, but configuring a router to permit TCP connection packets and drop data packets would be an unusual configuration. I'd be more suspicious of a specialized network device than a normal router. Something doing enterprise-grade NAT, intrusion detection, traffic shaping, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is something wrong with your key? You can try and login with a username and password just to make sure its not the key. This wont work if sshd is setup to only accept keys though. Here is an example

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -p 2221 username@my-server
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions on your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. They should be 0600.

Check the permissions on the home (~) directory and not just the `~/.ssh`
directory.

Alternatively you can create a new set of keys and try:

- `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
- `Enter file in which to save the key (/home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa):` Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- `Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):` Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

It'll look something like this:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/demo/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
4a:dd:0a:c6:35:4e:3f:ed:27:38:8c:74:44:4d:93:67 demo@a
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|          .oo.   |
|         .  o.E  |
|        + .  o   |
|     . = = .     |
|      = S = .    |
|     o + = +     |
|      . o + o .  |
|           . o   |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

The `id_rsa` keys will be something :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Check for the integrity of that and try again.

Comment: He will also need to copy his pub key to the server using this: `ssh-copy-id user@hostname.example.com` (I also upvoted u, i am sure its his key too)

Comment: I didn't use the key pairs, so I don't think this is caused by the key issue. Anyway, I've changed the permission of authorized_keys to 600, still no luck.

Comment: @NeilWang, you didn't use the key pairs? Did you set up the SSH server so that keys are used? Did you set up the client to connect to the server using a specific key? Otherwise, do  `username@my-server -p 2221`.  I think you're trying to connect as the `root` user?